# Representing inner product between a Matrix and column vector, pseudo inverse, and projection

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, pseudoinverse

The inner product of two column vectors v and w is defined as:

$$v \cdot w = w \cdot v = <v,w>=v^T w = <w,v>= w^T v =|proj_w(v)| = |proj_v(w)| = \text{a scalar value}$$

Now if I were to generalize this concept of Inner product between a Matrix A and **column vector** x,  What do we call this type of inner product?  and how do we define the order of the matrix in the inner product operator $<A,x>$ verses $<A,x>$...

do we write $A^T x$ as $<A,x>$

... or do we write $A^T x$ as $<x, A>$?

Does Projection of A onto x equal:

$$|proj_x(A)| = <A,x> / <A,A>$$

or does it equal:

$$|proj_x(A)| = <x,A> / <A,A>$$

Given Pseduo inverse:

$$x=Ay$$
$$A^Tx=A^TAy$$
$$y=\frac{A^Tx}{A^TA}$$

$$A^{\dagger} = \frac{A^T}{A^TA}$$

$$y=A^{\dagger}x$$

thus, pseudo inverse corresponds to an orthogonal projection of vector x onto the manifold of A...

can we say:

$$A^{\dagger}x = proj_x(A)$$?

or would that be:

$$A^{\dagger}x = proj_A(x)$$?

Comment: An inner product has a very specific meaning, in what way is this a generalisation?

Comment: 0


Because usually they only specify inner product between two vectors where the order of which vector you select first doesn’t matter... but when you do the inner product of a matrix and a vector the order matters and to make things more confusing I can’t find any examples of a matrix and vector inner product that confirms the correct ordering in the inner product braces < ,> is it matrix first or matrix last?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'a matrix and vector inner product'. Pick a different term. The term inner product has a very specific meaning and you do not seem to be describing anything by way of a natural generalisation.

Comment: Ok... in that case is it, $Proj_A(x)$ or $Proj_x(A)$?  Projection of A onto x, or Projection of x onto A?

Comment: I would vote for $proj_A(x)$ because it would make move sense to subscript the orthogonal basis vectors comprising matrix A to translate vector x ,,,

Comment: $v^Tw\ne vw^T$. The first is a scalar, but the second is an $n\times n$ matrix. I expect that you meant to write $w^Tv$ instead. Second, $v^Tw\ne proj_w(v)$ unless $w$ is a unit vector. I will also point out that $\langle v,w\rangle = v^Tw$ is only one of an infinite number of possible inner products of two vectors.

Comment: Moving on to later in your question, if by division by the matrix $A^TA$ you mean multiplication by its inverse, how do you know that this inverse exists?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  should read: $w^Tv=v^Tw$.   Sure there are a few cases that are not inverable... but, there are many cases that are invertable...

Comment: Inner products have important and useful properties related to (or from a different perspective, defining) the geometry of the vector space. What useful or interesting properties do you want this “generalization” of yours to have?

Comment: I was just trying to figure out what it means to project x onto A, by multiply it by the pseudo inverse....

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC7l96tW8V8